# How to set a dynamic cookie on laravel 5.6 or JavaScript using js-cookie

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5.6

Before hand my english is not my native language so... sorry for all the spelling/typos and else.

I'm working on this site and it requires to show a promotional video to all users (it needs to be a modal). Here are the conditions:

The promotional video needs to be shown on any page of the site.

If a user saw the promotion, it will be displayed again a week later to the same user (if the promo is still active).

If the promotional video is deleted by another promotional video it has to show the new promotional video (ex: if a user visits the site and saw the promotion on day 1 and on day 3 the promotion its deleted or it expired and another promotion its set, it needs to be displayed to that same user if it visits the site again before the week has passed).

I was thinking on using a laravel cookie but I was told that using them is not a good practice. If so, why?

Right now the App is using js-cookie and some cookies are set using it. Is it possible to acomplish what I want with it?

This are some parts of my code

on my ViewServiceProvider.php I have this

```
public function boot()
{
    View::composer('layouts.partials.modals', PromotionalVideoComposer::class);

}
```

On the PromotionalVideoComposer.php

```
public function compose(View $view)
{
    $view->with('promotionalVideo', PromotionalVideo::active()->pluck('link')->first());
}
```

On the partiasl.modals.blade.php

```
// some modals

<!-- Modal Promotional Video -->
@if (isset($promotionalVideo))
    <div class="modal fade modal-player" id="promotional-video" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" dusk="close-promotional-video"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <div class="modal-body player-container">
                        <iframe src="{{ $promotionalVideo }}" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- .modal-header -->
            </div><!-- .modal-content -->
        </div><!-- .modal-dialog modal-lg -->
    </div><!-- .modal fade -->
@endif
```

and the app.js

```
if (Cookie.get('promotionalVideoDisplayed') === undefined) {
    $('#promotional-video').modal('show');
    Cookie.set('promotionalVideoDisplayed', true, { expires: 7 });
}

// On close video modal stop/delete video iframe
$("#promotional-video").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    var $iframe = "#promotional-video iframe";

    $($iframe).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using cookies (which can be deleted or not set so showing the same video multiple times) I would suggest adding a db entry for "user id" , "promotion id" and "last viewed" date.

Then read from that to decide whether to show the video or not.

Comment: That will work for registered users, but what about guests?
Can I try to argument that guests are not likely to visit the site frequently so it needs another kind of approach for them?

Comment: Use a cookie for guests and a DB entry for logged-in users